# NHibernate stops if unique constraint has been violated previously

Tags: nhibernate

I have a tiny problem with NHibernate and I can't figure out why. Every time I debug or profile the application and I accidently violate a unique constraint NHibernate just won't run any more multiqueries (I'll leave the exception stack trace till last). The flow is this. Everything works fine and then:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'UQ__workday__572F4CF4753864A1'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.workday'. The statement has been
>   terminated.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'UQ__workday__572F4CF4753864A1'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.workday'. The statement has been
>   terminated.terminated.

If I now try to run the same code that executes the query:

```
var query1 = QueryOver.Of<Invoice>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Company).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.Workdays).Eager
    .Where(x => x.Id == invoiceId);

var query2 = QueryOver.Of<Invoice>()
    .Fetch(x => x.Company).Eager
    .Fetch(x => x.Products).Eager
    .Where(x => x.Id == invoiceId);

var result = Session.CreateMultiCriteria()
    .Add(query1)
    .Add(query2)
    .List();

var invoice = ((IList) result[0])[0] as Invoice;

if (invoice != null) {
    invoice.CalculateTotals();
}

return invoice;
```

That code generates the following statement

```
SELECT this_.invoice_id         as invoice1_10_2_,
       this_.invoice_number     as invoice2_10_2_,
       this_.invoice_prefix     as invoice3_10_2_,
       this_.start_date         as start4_10_2_,
       this_.end_date           as end5_10_2_,
       this_.period             as period10_2_,
       this_.km                 as km10_2_,
       this_.km_price           as km8_10_2_,
       this_.hour_price         as hour9_10_2_,
       this_.gst                as gst10_2_,
       this_.customer_id        as customer11_10_2_,
       this_.printed            as printed10_2_,
       this_.created_at         as created13_10_2_,
       this_.created_by         as created14_10_2_,
       this_.updated_at         as updated15_10_2_,
       this_.updated_by         as updated16_10_2_,
       this_.deleted_at         as deleted17_10_2_,
       this_.deleted_by         as deleted18_10_2_,
       this_.company_id         as company19_10_2_,
       workdays2_.invoice_id    as invoice10_4_,
       workdays2_.workday_id    as workday1_4_,
       workdays2_.workday_id    as workday1_15_0_,
       workdays2_.created_at    as created2_15_0_,
       workdays2_.created_by    as created3_15_0_,
       workdays2_.updated_at    as updated4_15_0_,
       workdays2_.updated_by    as updated5_15_0_,
       workdays2_.quantity      as quantity15_0_,
       workdays2_.unit_price    as unit7_15_0_,
       workdays2_.day           as day15_0_,
       workdays2_.description   as descript9_15_0_,
       workdays2_.invoice_id    as invoice10_15_0_,
       company3_.company_id     as company1_12_1_,
       company3_.created_at     as created2_12_1_,
       company3_.created_by     as created3_12_1_,
       company3_.updated_at     as updated4_12_1_,
       company3_.updated_by     as updated5_12_1_,
       company3_.name           as name12_1_,
       company3_.bankgiro_nr    as bankgiro7_12_1_,
       company3_.invoice_prefix as invoice8_12_1_,
       company3_.moms_reg_nr    as moms9_12_1_,
       company3_.plus_giro_nr   as plus10_12_1_,
       company3_.contact_person as contact11_12_1_,
       company3_.email          as email12_1_,
       company3_.mobile         as mobile12_1_,
       company3_.phone          as phone12_1_,
       company3_.fax            as fax12_1_
FROM   [invoice] this_
       left outer join [workday] workdays2_
         on this_.invoice_id = workdays2_.invoice_id
       left outer join [company] company3_
         on this_.company_id = company3_.company_id
WHERE  this_.invoice_id = 351 /* @p0 */
SELECT this_.invoice_id         as invoice1_10_2_,
       this_.invoice_number     as invoice2_10_2_,
       this_.invoice_prefix     as invoice3_10_2_,
       this_.start_date         as start4_10_2_,
       this_.end_date           as end5_10_2_,
       this_.period             as period10_2_,
       this_.km                 as km10_2_,
       this_.km_price           as km8_10_2_,
       this_.hour_price         as hour9_10_2_,
       this_.gst                as gst10_2_,
       this_.customer_id        as customer11_10_2_,
       this_.printed            as printed10_2_,
       this_.created_at         as created13_10_2_,
       this_.created_by         as created14_10_2_,
       this_.updated_at         as updated15_10_2_,
       this_.updated_by         as updated16_10_2_,
       this_.deleted_at         as deleted17_10_2_,
       this_.deleted_by         as deleted18_10_2_,
       this_.company_id         as company19_10_2_,
       products2_.invoice_id    as invoice10_4_,
       products2_.product_id    as product1_4_,
       products2_.product_id    as product1_13_0_,
       products2_.created_at    as created2_13_0_,
       products2_.created_by    as created3_13_0_,
       products2_.updated_at    as updated4_13_0_,
       products2_.updated_by    as updated5_13_0_,
       products2_.quantity      as quantity13_0_,
       products2_.profit_rate   as profit7_13_0_,
       products2_.unit_price    as unit8_13_0_,
       products2_.description   as descript9_13_0_,
       products2_.invoice_id    as invoice10_13_0_,
       company3_.company_id     as company1_12_1_,
       company3_.created_at     as created2_12_1_,
       company3_.created_by     as created3_12_1_,
       company3_.updated_at     as updated4_12_1_,
       company3_.updated_by     as updated5_12_1_,
       company3_.name           as name12_1_,
       company3_.bankgiro_nr    as bankgiro7_12_1_,
       company3_.invoice_prefix as invoice8_12_1_,
       company3_.moms_reg_nr    as moms9_12_1_,
       company3_.plus_giro_nr   as plus10_12_1_,
       company3_.contact_person as contact11_12_1_,
       company3_.email          as email12_1_,
       company3_.mobile         as mobile12_1_,
       company3_.phone          as phone12_1_,
       company3_.fax            as fax12_1_
FROM   [invoice] this_
       left outer join [product] products2_
         on this_.invoice_id = products2_.invoice_id
       left outer join [company] company3_
         on this_.company_id = company3_.company_id
WHERE  this_.invoice_id = 351 /* @p1 */
```

I get the following really frustrating exception. Actually from now on every query is a timeout and the application needs to be restarted before I can execute anything. Sometimes it doesn't even help to restart it.

Does anyone know what is up with that?

> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet
>   bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader
>   ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String
>   resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method,
>   DbAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   Boolean returnStream, String method)
>   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   at
>   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand
>   cmd) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:line
>   247    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.MultiCriteriaImpl.GetResultsFromDatabase(IList
>   results) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\MultiCriteriaImpl.cs:line
>   209    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.MultiCriteriaImpl.DoList()
>   in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\MultiCriteriaImpl.cs:line
>   171    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.MultiCriteriaImpl.ListIgnoreQueryCache()
>   in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\MultiCriteriaImpl.cs:line
>   143    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.MultiCriteriaImpl.List()
>   in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\MultiCriteriaImpl.cs:line
>   91    at
>   FakturaLight.Repositories.InvoiceRepository.GetSingle(Int32
>   invoiceId) in
>   D:\Projekt\faktura_light\src\FakturaLight\Repositories\InvoiceRepository.cs:line
>   168    at
>   FakturaLight.WebClient.Controllers.InvoiceController.PrepareEditInvoiceModel(EditInvoiceModel
>   oldModel, Int32 id) in
>   D:\Projekt\faktura_light\src\FakturaLight.WebClient\Controllers\InvoiceController.cs:line
>   116    at
>   FakturaLight.WebClient.Controllers.InvoiceController.Edit(Int32
>   id) in
>   D:\Projekt\faktura_light\src\FakturaLight.WebClient\Controllers\InvoiceController.cs:line
>   82    at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func`1 continuation)preContext, Func`1 continuation)1.terminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's by design. Just create another session.

> If the Session throws an exception,
>   the transaction must be rolled back
>   and the session discarded.

*(please remember that your sessions should be opened late and closed early)*

Comment: I was actually thinking about that yesterday not being happy at all with the mega transactions I run at the moment. Will have to wait until the next release though. :) Thanks